# iPad WebView - Looking for Dock.Fill like behavior in UISplitView

Tags: ipad, webview, uisplitviewcontroller

How do I make view that is in a UISplitView (Detail side) fill its container. Similar to Visual Studio's Dock.Fill in Windows development?

Must be done in code.

The view is there already, just needs to grow to fill the container at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the autoresizingMask. You can do this in code:

```
[detailView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```